# How to add maven.fabric.io/public to artifactory/nexus and download passthrough io.fabric.tools:gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory

Is available build.gradle

```sh
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://artifactory/artifactory/repo' }
        maven { url 'http://artifactory/artifactory/remote-repos' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'
        ....
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://artifactory/artifactory/repo' }
        maven { url 'http://artifactory/artifactory/remote-repos' }
    }
}

}
```

He gives an error.
When trying to add https://maven.fabric.io/public to artifactory, an error is thrown.

Has anyone encountered such an error? And how can it be fixed?

```sh
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0.
         > Could not get resource 'http://artifactory/artifactory/repo/io/fabric/tools/gradle/1.29.0/gradle-1.29.0.pom'.
```

Comment: Which version of Artifactory are you using? is 'repo' as virtual repository? did you create a remote repository pointing at fabric and included it in the virtual repo?

Answer (score 1):

I added https://maven.fabric.io/public to artifactory. It is work